# Regular expression with URL Encoded Strings

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I have strings that contain URL encoding (%22) and other characters [!@#$%^&*]. I need to use a RegEx to check if the string contains a character within that group but exclude the URL encoded quote (%22). I can't get the negative look ahead to work properly nor am I able to get an excluded string (or negation) working either. Can someone help? Here is code so far that doesn't work:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[!@#$%^&*]"); //
String[] tokens = {"%22Hobo%22", "Shoe*", "Rail%6Road","Sugar"};
for (String string : tokens) {
  Matcher m = p.matcher(string);
  boolean b = m.find()
  System.out.println(string + ": " + b);
}
```

The desired output should be false, true, true, false.

Comment: Whyo you do not use a URLEncoder?

Comment: What I put in the example was for ease and readability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(?!%22)[!@#$%^&*]
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/mS3tQ7/16

Comment: Thanks vks, this is it. I was so close but had a few too many expressions.

Answer (score 0):

```
export const uriParser = (x) =>
  //replace/regex exclude-negated [set-of-tokens], doesn't work/parse for (%[A-Fa-f0-9]{2})+
  //decodeURI() does the same I believe, but this will always return a string,
  //without an error object
  //a-z or A-Z includes underscore '_' but not space whitespace, nor (\r\n|\r|\n)+
  x.replace(/(%[A-Fa-f0-9]{2})+[^a-zA-Z0-9-+ ]+/g, "_");
```

[https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt#:~:text=2.4.%20%20When%20to%20Encode%20or%20Decode%0A](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt#:%7E:text=2.4.%20%20When%20to%20Encode%20or%20Decode%0A)

for my purposes I make my uri link fragmens go thru `(%[A-Fa-f0-9]{2})+` on mount so I use `.replace("_"," ")` for ui but `uriParser()` for outgoing links in ux to bypass redundancy as much as possible.  The use case choice is between getting a string always & putting specifications for other characters before this. "Whyo you do not use a URLEncoder?" – Jens' comment on question